# How to combine two arrays with duplicated values and differences in array length?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to have one array in result and I want also have all values of the arrays even if they has the same values.

I have tried `array_combine()`, but with the duplicate keys it is not possible.

I've also tried `$array1 + $array2`, but that isn't the desired result either.

These are my sample input arrays:

```
$array1 = array(10) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(0) "" 
    [2]=> string(2) "12" 
    [3]=> string(2) "41" 
    [4]=> string(1) "5" 
    [5]=> string(1) "6" 
    [6]=> string(0) "" 
    [7]=> string(2) "11" 
    [8]=> string(2) "23" 
    [9]=> string(2) "10" }

$array2 = array(11) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "A" 
    [1]=> string(1) "B" 
    [2]=> string(1) "C" 
    [3]=> string(1) "D" 
    [4]=> string(1) "E" 
    [5]=> string(1) "F" 
    [6]=> string(1) "G" 
    [7]=> string(1) "H" 
    [8]=> string(1) "I" 
    [9]=> string(2) "J" 
    [10]=> string(1) "K" }
```

I should have output data like this:

```
 $array = array(11){
    [1]=> string(1) "A" 
    []=> string(1) "B" 
    [12]=> string(1) "C" 
    [41]=> string(1) "D" 
    [5]=> string(1) "E" 
    [6]=> string(1) "F" 
    []=> string(1) "G" 
    [11]=> string(1) "H" 
    [23]=> string(1) "I" 
    [10]=> string(2) "J" 
    []=> string(1) "K" }
```

Comment: So you want to have the same (empty) key multiple times? That's not possible. Keys are unique and how would you access this `[]=> string(1) "B"`?

Comment: array keys should be unique, just as magnus said, you could use `array2` as keys though

Comment: I am noticing that these two arrays have different lengths.  Were you hoping to have a key of `NULL`? or two empty keys within the same output array?  Doesn't look well thought out.

Comment: Just FYI, it's easier ( on me ) if you print them using `var_export` not `var_dump`,  Is it sad I know you used var_dump `:-/`

Comment: Your question cannot be solved.  The best you can hope for is to flip your logic and ask for `$array2` to be the keys and `$array1` to be the values -- if you want to establish some sort of relationship between the two arrays.

Comment: Yes I use var_dump, so I can't have one array with the all values of the two arrays even if exists the same values?

Comment: Again. **_array keys are unique_** so no, you can't have the same key multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `array_combine` because `array_combine` expects the arrays to be the same size. And in fact, the output you ask for is not possible. Array keys need to be unique. You cannot have

```
[]=> string(1) "B"
[]=> string(1) "G" 
[]=> string(1) "K"
```

as these would overwrite each other. You'd end up with only K.

An alternative would be to assign an array when there are multiple values per key, e.g.

```
[]=> array(3) ["B", "G", "K"]
```

There is no built-in function for this though. You'll have to manually iterate both arrays and assign the values as needed. A simple solution would be to use a `MultipleIterator` because it can easily deal with differently sized arrays:

```
$keys = new ArrayIterator(["", 1, "", 2, "", 3]);
$values = new ArrayIterator(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]);

$flags = MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC;
$pairs = new MultipleIterator($flags);
$pairs->attachIterator($keys, 'key');
$pairs->attachIterator($values, 'value');

$combined = [];
foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
    $key = $pair['key'];
    $val = $pair['value'];
    if (!isset($combined[$key])) {
        $combined[$key] = $val;
        continue;
    }
    if (!is_array($combined[$key])) {
        $combined[$key] = [$combined[$key]];
    }
    $combined[$key][] = $val;
}

print_r($combined);
```

This would then produce:

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => C
            [2] => E
            [3] => G
        )

    [1] => B
    [2] => D
    [3] => F
)
```

Comment: ok thanks, so `array_combine($array2, $array1)` is the best solution?

Comment: No, array_combine requires the two arrays to be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the two arrays then you can use `$array2`'s values as keys because they are unique (and it is the longer array so, `$array1` won't get cut off).

```
$array1=["1","","12","41","5","6","","11","23","10"];
$array2=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"];

foreach($array2 as $i=>$v){
    $result[$v]=(isset($array1[$i])?$array1[$i]:NULL);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'A' => '1',
  'B' => '',
  'C' => '12',
  'D' => '41',
  'E' => '5',
  'F' => '6',
  'G' => '',
  'H' => '11',
  'I' => '23',
  'J' => '10',
  'K' => NULL,
)
```

Alternatively, you could pad `$array1` then combine:

```
$array1=["1","","12","41","5","6","","11","23","10"];
$array2=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"];
$array1=array_pad($array1,sizeof($array2),NULL);
$result=array_combine($array2,$array1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_merge like below:

```
print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

or you can use array_combine: array_combine(keys,values);

```
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");

$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
print_r($c);
```

Alert: But you can't duplicate the keys.

Comment: and how for the same values? I want to show the values whenever it's the same because with `array_combine` it's combine the values in one?

Comment: You mean you are expecting to get the result for $array1 and $array2 to be everything included in merged array? Like if you have 10 element in $array1 and 10 elements in $array2, you want to get array with 20 elements?

Comment: Well, it appears the Upvote Pixies have undermined the justified downvotes on this incorrect answer.  The upvote will ensure that this unsuitable answer remains on the page to confuse future SO readers.